# TS Error with `lodash-es` using ionic2, Typescript, RollupJs, es2015 modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic2, rollupjs

I'm using `lodash` with the new `ionic2@RC.0` project template, which includes

- Typescript
- Rollup
- es2015 modules

This works for me:

```
npm install lodash --save
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev --save-exact
// typescript
import _ from "lodash";
```

But apparently `lodash-es` is recommended with `Rollup` because of the tree-shaking thing. But when I do this:

```
npm install lodash-es --save  // instead of `lodash`
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev --save-exact
// typescript
import _ from "lodash-es";
```

I get a `Typescript` error

`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash-es'.`

However, the transpiled `javascript` actually works and runs correctly.  What gives?

here is my `tsconfig`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that no one has created a typings file for lodash-es so the Typescript compiler can't validate.

Comment: We've made the typescript team aware, but frankly, it's really up to the community.

Comment: @icfantv can you link up here the issue where your entry is concerning this

Comment: @ESturzenegger, this was at an on-site meeting with a couple of members of the MSFT TS team.  they took notes, but this isn't a TS issue, per se, rather a lodash and lodash community one:  https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1835.